# Add a searchbox to the body of a page

Tags: customization, pages, search, editor, body-class

I'm creating a website in which I need that, when I click on one of the tabs of the specific menu, and it opens, this page contains a search box in its body.
My question is how can I add this search box to the page, where can it be edited.

I've now started using WordPress, I've been doing a search but I haven't found anything that specifically answers me.

Comment: The best you can do is to put the `get_search_form` in a shortcode and use that shortcode in the content of your page.

Answer (score 2):

It's just a form that takes a GET parameter named `s`.

Example:

```
<form method="get" action="/">
<input type="text" name="s" placeholder="type here to search">
</form>
```

But I recommend using the function called `get_search_form()` that does basically the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the block editor, as of WordPress 5.3 there is a Search block that you can use: https://wordpress.org/support/article/search-block/